# Python Line count of output

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code working but now I am trying to add a line count at the end.

```
print "Looking for abc"
for line1 in open("file.txt"):
    if "abc" in line1:
        print line1,
```

I can get it to print just fine of course, but having trouble figuring out how to get a final line count?

Comment: `count += 1` in the loop, and `print(count)` in the end.

Comment: Thank you .. is there a way to just get the final total vs. each line getting a number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with a counter you can edit yours to be

```
print "Looking for abc"
count = 0
for line1 in open("file.txt"):
    if "abc" in line1:
        print line1,
        count += 1
print count
```

Or if you wanted a more pythonic way you could say

```
lines = [line for line in open('file.txt') if 'abc' in line]
for line in lines:
    print line,
print len(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install rglob
```

Then pass a lambda filter function to lcount method

```
import rglob
filter=lambda x: True if ("abc" in x) else False
rglob.lcount("/file/base/path/","file.txt",filter)
```